# Serving static websites from S3 through Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a rails app that will run on my main domain, which will have a bunch of subdomains that will all be separate static websites.

I want the files for these static sites to each be in their own folder on an S3 bucket I created. So, going to mysite.example.com you would see the index.html file in the mysite folder on S3. The user's browser would also have to be able to pull any of the CSS and images referenced in index.html

Is there any way to do this? If possible I would like to do this off of Heroku, but that might not be feasible.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't choosing to serve these static websites from a hosting provider like BlueHost or your own Heroku account instead? S3 is geared more towards storage than a web-server.

Comment: Yes I think I've decided to set up apache to serve all the subdomains itself and just have rails for the main site.

Answer (score 0):

The [right_aws](http://rightaws.rubyforge.org/) gem might be exactly what you're looking for; it claims to offer S3 and EC2 support, among other services.